# finitely presented groups of exponential growth

Tags: group-theory

Does there exists a finitely presented group of exponential growth which does not contain free sub-semigroups (of rank $\geq 2$)?

Comment: I think this is a difficult question. You could try asking it on MathOverflow. A good candidate would be a finitely presented infinite torsion group, because that would certainly not contain a free subsemigroup, and it would have a good chance of having exponential growth. The problem with that is that it is still an open question whether such groups exist, although it is widely believed that they do.

Comment: I don't know anything about free semigroups, but what about a solvable group that is not virtually nilpotent? Something like $\langle a,b,c\ |\ [a,b]=1, a^c=a^2b, b^c=ab\rangle$. Just seems like "solvable" and "free" shouldn't mix.

Comment: I guess this group contains the lamplighter group and hence a free semi-group.

Comment: Let me also add that for elementary amenable groups exponential growth is equivalent to containing free semigroups.

Comment: Steve D: I convinced myself that $c^2$ and $c^2a$ generate a free semigroup in your example. I suspect that examples like this will all turn out to have free subsemigroups.